# Programmatically create UIToolbar with default height

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

There are a number of questions regarding the height of `UIToolbar`, but I don't see one where the height is obtained dynamically. Is there a way to create a `UIToolbar` with the correct default height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the toolbar with 0 height, then call `sizeToFit`. The toolbar will then have the default height.

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 0)];
[toolbar sizeToFit];
```

Swift version:

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 0))
toolbar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Would the behaviour be any different if initialized with a non-zero height?

Comment: @justintime is been a long time since I wrote this up, but my guess is that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using UINavigationController

```
navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
```

This will give default navigation controller toolbar with default height